# MySQL query to create a Matrix view using pivot

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a table with the following fields:

```
p1
p2
s1
s2
```

where p1 -> player1, p2 -> player2, s1 -> game1, s2 -> game2
The number of players can vary from 3 - 10.
The table have the results between them.
For example let's suppose that we have 4 players:
TIM, ROB, NICK, GEORGE
and the matches between them:

```
    p1     p2       s1  s2
    TIM    ROB      4   0
    NICK   GEORGE   4   0
    TIM    NICK     0   4
    ROB    GEORGE   4   0
    TIM    GEORGE   4   0
    ROB    NICK     4   0
```

What I want to produce with the query is something like this:

```
           TIM   ROB   NICK   GEORGE
    TIM     X    4-0   0-4     4-0
    ROB    0-4    X    4-0     4-0
    NICK   0-4   4-0    X      4-0
    GEORGE 0-4   0-4   0-4      X
```

Is it possible somehow in MySQL?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have found a similar question but it's applied on TSQL and it's not exactly the same presentation... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334751/squash-league-results-sql-query/32340699#32340699

Comment: [Generic pivot code](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot).

Answer (score 0):

Example pivot tracking table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mail_track` (
`ID` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 MemberID mediumint(7) default NULL,
`MessageTitle` varchar(20) default NULL,
`Type` varchar(6) default NULL,
`URLID` varchar(15) default NULL,
`DateTime` datetime default NULL,
`IP` varchar(15) default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
KEY `DateTime` (`DateTime`,`Type`,`MessageTitle`,`MemberID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=199952834 ;
```

pivot query

```
SELECT 
SUM( IF( mail_track.Type = 'Open', 1, 0 ) ) AS Opens,
SUM( IF( mail_track.Type = 'Click', 1, 0 ) ) AS Clicks,
SUM( IF( mail_track.Type = 'Sent', 1, 0 ) ) AS Sent,
DATE(DateTime)
FROM mail_track GROUP BY DATE(DateTime)
```